# Как исправить данную ошибку System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Элемент с указанным именем не существует." и как сделать рамку таблицы?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

вот мой код экспорта данных из datagridview в файл C# таблицей

```
class WordExporter
{ 
    public static void WordExport(DataGridView DGV, string filename)
    {
        if (DGV.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            int RowCount = DGV.Rows.Count;
            int ColumnCount = DGV.Columns.Count;
            Object[,] DataArray = new object[RowCount + 1, ColumnCount + 1];

            //add rows
            int r = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
                for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
                {
                    DataArray[r, c] = DGV.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                } //end row loop
            } //end column loop

            Word.Document oDoc = new Word.Document();
            oDoc.Application.Visible = true;

            //page orintation
            oDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;


            dynamic oRange = oDoc.Content.Application.Selection.Range;
            string oTemp = "";
            for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
                {
                    oTemp = oTemp + DataArray[r, c] + "\t";

                }
            }

            //table format
            oRange.Text = oTemp;

            object Separator = Word.WdTableFieldSeparator.wdSeparateByTabs;
            object ApplyBorders = true;
            object AutoFit = true;
            object AutoFitBehavior = Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent;

            oRange.ConvertToTable(ref Separator, ref RowCount, ref ColumnCount,
                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ref ApplyBorders,
                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                  Type.Missing, ref AutoFit, ref AutoFitBehavior, Type.Missing);

            oRange.Select();

            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Select();
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = 0;
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Alignment = 0;
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
            oDoc.Application.Selection.InsertRowsAbove(1);
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();

            //header row style
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Bold = 1;
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Size = 14;

            //add header row manually
            for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
                oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Text = DGV.Columns[c].HeaderText;
            }

            //table style 
            Word.Table newTable = oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1];
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Range.Font.Size = 14;
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].set_Style("Table Grid 8");
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;

            //header text
            foreach (Word.Section section in oDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections)
            {
                Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                headerRange.Text = "your header text";
                headerRange.Font.Size = 16;
                headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            }

            //save the file
            oDoc.SaveAs(filename);

            //NASSIM LOUCHANI
        }
    }
```

высвечивает такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам я новичок и пока ничо не смыслю в создании документа и внесения в него данных так шо строго не судите я этот код нашел и подделал под свой.Подскажите как добавить рамки таблицы и что не так и что надо добавить.Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Что такое `Table Grid 8`?

Comment: При чем тут метки winforms и mysql-workbanch? Ошибка явно говорит о том, что стиль, который вы пытаетесь установить, не найден и, вероятнее всего, не существует в принципе, т.к. наименования стилей могут зависеть как от версии, так и от локализации ms word. Лучше либо явно задайте параметры ячеек, либо используйте шаблон документа. в котором все уже настроено.

Comment: да ты прав я просмотрел много стилей и оказывается таких нету